# Select por dias do mês retornando 0 quando não houver nenhum registro daquele dia

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma base de dados de chamados da empresa, para exemplo digamos que a tabela tenha apenas:

```
-- TABELA CHAMADO --
id (id do chamado)
inicio (data de inicio do chamado)
id_criador (id do usuário que abriu o chamado)
----------------------------------------------
```

Eu preciso elaborar um select que me diga quantos chamados cada usuário abriu em cada dia do mês, retornando 0 caso ele não tenha aberto nenhum, por exemplo.

```
id_criador      dia            qnt
1               2018-08-01     7
1               2018-08-02     0
1               2018-08-03     6
```

Já encontrei em outros tópicos o comando

```
generate_series(DATE'2018-08-01',DATE'2018-08-31',INTERVAL'1 day')
```

que me retorna todos os dias do mês, porém não estou conseguindo juntar esse resultado com os dados da tabela chamado. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa foi a melhor solução que encontrei. Espero possa ajuda-lo.

```
SELECT T2.id_criador, T2.dia, COALESCE(qnt, 0) AS qnt
FROM
   (
      SELECT inicio, COUNT(*) qnt, id_criador
      FROM chamado
      GROUP BY id_criador, inicio
   ) T1
   RIGHT JOIN
   (
      SELECT id_criador, dia
      FROM
      (
         SELECT date_trunc('day', dd) dia
         FROM
           generate_series(DATE'2018-08-01',DATE'2018-08-31',INTERVAL'1 day') dd
      ) AS d1 
      FULL JOIN
      (
          SELECT DISTINCT id_criador FROM  chamado C
          WHERE inicio BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31'
      ) AS D2
      ON 1=1
   ) T2
   ON T1.id_criador = T2.id_criador AND T1.inicio = T2.dia
ORDER BY id_criador, dia
```

[Aqui está a prova que o meu codigo está correto](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cec93/25)

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Apenas alterei o segundo select para desconsiderar as horas. SELECT  date_trunc('day', inicio) inicio, COUNT(*) qnt, id_criador
      FROM chamado
      GROUP BY id_criador, date_trunc('day', inicio)